# The blurred background of JQuery Mobile Popup

Tags: css, jquery-mobile, popup, popupwindow

I am trying to use JQM popup function, and the code as following:

```
<div data-role="popup" id="findinfo" data-dismissible="false" data-overlay-theme="b" class="ui-corner-all">
  <a href="#" data-rel="back" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-icon-delete ui-btn-icon-notext ui-btn-right">Close</a>
  <div data-role="header" data-theme="c">
    <h1>Type Select</h1>
  </div>
  <div data-role="content" class="ui-content">
    <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
      <input type="radio" name="Fruit" id="Apple" value="a" checked="checked" />
      <label for="Apple">Apple</label>
      <input type="radio" name="Fruit" id="Orange" value="o"/>
      <label for="Orange">Orange</label>
    </fieldset>
    </br>
    <input type="button" id="sendbtn" value="Add" onclick="SelInfo()" data-theme="c"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

But the blurred background is cut when popup not call at the top of window as:

[image]

When I scroll up, the blurred background shows gradually as [Fig 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QLHbn.png).

How could I make the blurred background full size no matter where the popup function pop up?

Answer (score 0):

I didnt test this code but, according to [documentation](https://api.jquerymobile.com/classes/), this should work.

```
.ui-overlay-shadow {
    position: fixed !important;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work. This code only makes the popup to full screen but not the background.